# How to link boost thread with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, boost, image-gallery

I have built Boost from the website using

```
./bootstrap.sh 
./b2 install
```

I think all are installed properly. I have headers in `/usr/local/include/boost` and libs in `/usr/local/lib`.

Everything links as long as don't include `boost/thread.hpp`:

```
// 
// main.cpp
// ising3
//
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
//#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace ::boost::tuples;
using namespace ::boost;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    tuple<int,int> a,b,c;
    a=make_tuple(1,1);
    b=make_tuple(3,2);

    std::cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Runs and prints:

```
Hello, World!
(1 1)
```

However, if uncommented, it fails:

[image]

I have linked the dynamic library libboost_thread.a and libboost_thread.dylib and included /usr/local/include into header search path and /usr/local/lib into library search path.

Comment: I've trimmed your excessive question. Screenshots are bad, unless you **cannot** copy/paste the relevant text. People cannot be expected to read that mess, and you had buried your error message in one of 8 (eight!!!?!) screenshots.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://superuser.com/q/818968/93541.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also link to `boost_system`.

The error indicates that it needs `boost::system::system_category` (which exists for error reporting).

Comment: do you mean this two library? libboost_filesystem-mt.a libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib

Comment: I succeeded by linking libboost_system-mt.a and libboost_system-mt.dylib . Thank you

Comment: I hope you learned that (a) asking a good question takes care & attention (b) reading the answer takes the same :) Cheers

Comment: Thank you soooo much for your help:) I have been trying all day long without success and just got a bit frustrated and just try to give some pictures to show exactly what's happening. Thank you. I will learn that.

Comment: I am having the same error.  I managed to trace back the problem to a call to the gcc-atomic.hp header file.  It seems as if the gcc compiler is supposed to provide information and is not doing so, which to me indicates it does not work with Xcode.  I linked the glibbest_system-mt.a and glibbest_system-mt.dylib in the same way I link boost.framework and it has not helped.  How did you solve this problem?